# AlertDialog in Android app not showing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am attempting to create an alert dialog, but it does not appear when I run my application. Here is my code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
            buildLocationMessage();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
```

Just add the setButton for "No"

Comment: Still nothing. I'm also getting a warning that the method setButton is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled,do you want to enable it?");

builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

//do stuff
startActivity(
     new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
   }
});

builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Did not work. This is essentially the same code, just spaced out more no? Just wondering if I missed a change you made!

Comment: I made change recently. Try the recent update above.

Comment: Yeah, I saw and used your edit. What's really odd about this, is that this is basically the same code I used previously that worked, but now in a different place it is not working

Comment: If it worked at one place, it should work at another place as well. You can debug to ensure the exact line error.

Comment: I have debugged and it runs through everything. It hits alert.show() and then decides to do nothing, which is what is confusing to me. There's no crash or anything, it simply does not appear.